Raspberry pi servo only moves when using varialbe duty in a while loop python
I am a beginner with programming on with GPIO and i am trying to understand servo's. Right now have a code that moves the servo 180 degrees in stepts with 2. This is in a while loop. But when i use the same command but outside the while loop it does nothing for example servo.ChangDutyCycle(6) does nothing. In the while loop i also need to use duty if a use a contant for example 4,6,8 etc the servo doesn't move. Can someone explain pls.
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
servo = GPIO.PWM(11,50)



servo.start(0)
time.sleep(1)

servo.ChangeDutyCycle(2)
# give no movement
duty = 2

while duty <=12:
        servo.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
        # using a constant instead of duty result is no movement
        time.sleep(1)
        # time.sleep(0.3)
#         # servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
#         # time.sleep(0.7)
        duty = duty + 2

I found that poeple use gpiozero but would like to use GPIO. And i can't get my servo to reverse on command. think that has to do with it doesn;t react if i have a constant in ChangeDutyCycle(contant)

dc is not the pulse duration in milliseconds, but the percentage of the pulse period that is on high. You need to calculate the duty cycle corresponding to the pulse duration you want.

I have tried but still seams do to nothing.

If you want to see the effect of calling servo.ChangeDutyCycle(2), then you need to actually delay/sleep in your program for some time to give the servo time to move to that position before you call ChangeDutyCycle again.  Servos cannot move instantaneously.
